# Use of variables in Apache configuration

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

I have a number of largely identical configuration files in my Apache2 configuration, for configuring various subdomains. In most of these configuration files, only the name of the subdomain itself is different from the other files and thus I am trying to figure out if it is possible to set some sort of variable at the top of the config file to easily set things like `ServerName`, `DocumentRoot`, `ErrorLog`, `CustomLog`

A bit like (which obviously doesn't work):

```
subdomain=blog

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName ${subdomain}.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/${subdomain}.example.com/htdocs

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/${subdomain}.example.com_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/${subdomain}.example.com_access.log combined

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

An even smarter solution would be if the `subdomain` variable can be set through a regex from filename of the configfile.

I did find [Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html), but it just doesn't describe exactly what I want.

Running Apache 2.2 on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

A demo with Perl [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/module/ABW/Template-Toolkit-2.24/lib/Template/Toolkit.pod) (no need to learn Perl to use the `tpage` command installed with the module) :

Template file :

```
$ cat vhost.tpl
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName [% subdomain %].example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/[% subdomain %].example.com/htdocs

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/[% subdomain %].example.com_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/[% subdomain %].example.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuration generation :

```
$ tpage --define subdomain=domain.tld --interpolate vhost.tpl
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain.tld.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.tld.example.com/htdocs

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.tld.example.com_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.tld.example.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your most flexible option would be to use some external program to create your Apache configuration based on a template.  The traditional program for that on Unix would be [M4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), although there's probably something a bit less baroque these days.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used mod_macro to achieve most of what you are trying to do, but these days I use configuration management (puppet in my case, but any of them should be able to do this). Then you can build your configs using higher-level scripting languages.

There are heaps of examples of parameterised Apache vhost modules for puppet out there.

So I'd say if you're already using config management or are considering it, do that, otherwise have a look at mod_macro.

http://people.apache.org/~fabien/mod_macro/